# style 2 radio buttons when clicked in react

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have 2 hidden customized radio button components, when we click on the label the radio is checked.
I have added a functionality that when the radio is checked there's a styling effect that appears on the label (a border with padding and background). The issue here is that when I click on the other radio label, the same styling is duplicated even though there's only one radio button that is checked. Here's the parent component :

```js
<div className="flex lg:justify-center gap-2 lg:gap-6">
                    <EspaceCard
                        value="miami"
                        onChange={(e) =>
                            setValues((prev) => ({ ...prev, espace: e.target.value }))
                        }
                        checked={values.espace === 'miami'}
                        text="MIAMI ROOM"
                    />
                    <EspaceCard
                        onChange={(e) =>
                            setValues((prev) => ({ ...prev, espace: e.target.value }))
                        }
                        value="jungle"
                        checked={values.espace === 'jungle'}
                        text="JUNGLE ROOM"
                    />
</div>
```

Here's the individual radio button component: (EspaceCard)

```js
'use client'

import { ChangeEvent, useState } from 'react';

interface InputProps {
    text: string;
    value: string;
    checked?: boolean;
    onChange: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
}

const EspaceCard = ({ text, value, onChange, checked }: InputProps) => {
    const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(checked);
    
    return (
        <>
            <label
                htmlFor={text}
                onClick={() => setClicked(!clicked)}
                className={`p-4 rounded-lg ${
                    clicked ? 'border-gold border bg-light-gold' : ''
                }`}
            >
                <div className="box-border lg:w-52 text-center relative bg-black px-6 py-6 h-60 rounded-xl shadow-lg lg:hover:scale-110 transition-all cursor-pointer border-gold border-4 before:content-[''] before:absolute before:top-0 before:left-1/2 before:bg-gold before:h-2 before:rounded-b-full before:w-1/2 before:-translate-x-1/2 grid place-content-center">
                    <p className="text-xl lg:text-2xl font-bold text-gold">{text}</p>
                </div>
            </label>
            <input
                type="radio"
                id={text}
                name="espace"
                value={value}
                onChange={onChange}
                checked={checked}
                hidden
            />
        </>
    );
};
export default EspaceCard;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here to the local state `clicked` on your `EspaceCard` component. The state is managed independently for each instance of the component, so when you click on one radio label, the `clicked` state is updated for that specific instance, but not for the other instance.

just remove the local state `clicked` from `EspaceCard` component and manage the `checked` state through the `checked` prop

```html
<label
  htmlFor={text}
  className={`p-4 rounded-lg ${
    checked ? "border-gold border bg-light-gold" : ""
  }`}
  onClick={() => handleLabelClicked()}
>....</label>
```

where `handleLabelClicked` is a function that updates the `checked` value in the parent component so you have to pass this function as well to `EspaceCard` as props:

```js
const EspaceCard = ({ text, value, onChange, checked, handleLabelClicked  }: InputProps) => {
 //...
}
```